# Packet looping on interfaces attached to linux bridge

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I have added two ethernet interfaces on a linux bridge. I started seeing too many packets on the both connected interfaces by using tcpdump.

The tcpdump message is:

**IP 0.0.0.0 > 224.0.0.1: igmp quer v2**

The machine is virtual machine & has **centos OS 6.3** installed.

What is the reason both the interfaces are getting flooded with the igmp packets continiously? Its sort of loop. How to solve this?

The procedure I followed:

brctl addbr mybr
brctl addif mybr eth0
brctl addif mybr eth1
ifconfig mybr up

Comment: is a reserver 224.0.0.1 IANA multicast address = "The All Hosts multicast group addresses all hosts on the same network segment",so your linux bridge is working as layer 2 switch

Comment: @c4f4t0r These multicasts packets are getting flooded on both the attached interface on linux bridge. How can i stop this flooding?

Comment: try to disable the spanning tree

Comment: tried that also, but it doesn't stop flooding.

Comment: are you sure you don't have any software in your virtual machines doing igmp query? because i have a xen physical host with 4 sle 11 sp2 and i don't see any multicast traffic